# Power pivot specific day issue

Tags: powerpivot

I have two columns called

1ST column Calendar Date:

```
16/02/2015
```

2nd Column Previous Day:

```
Yes
```

Formula I am currently using:

```
if([calendar Date])=today-1,"YES","NO").
```

The 2nd column returns value based on the 1st column.

However , the problem I am getting is when I run the data on monday when we have calendar date (day on friday). So it is showing "NO" as formula only returns data for previous day.

So I want something like this
Only when I run on Monday it should give me     if([calendar Date])=today-3,"YES","NO").And all other workdays  if([calendar Date])=today-1,"YES","NO")

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you cell **A2** has the calender date then try with below formula.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=6,(IF(A2=TODAY()-3,"YES","NO")),(IF(A2=TODAY()-1,"YES","NO")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,IF(TODAY()-3 = A12, "YES", "NO"), IF(TODAY()-1 = A12, "YES", "NO"))
```

first, identify whether the date today is monday or the other day of the week.

```
IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2
```

If today is monday, then you can create the condition that the previous day must be friday [today()-3].

```
IF(TODAY()-3 = A12, "YES", "NO")
```

If today is not monday, then create the condition that the previous day is the date yesterday [today()-1].

```
IF(TODAY()-1 = A12, "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To disregard weekends and holidays, you will want either the [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7) or 
[NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28)¹ function. Not only can you skip a conventional Sat/Sun weekend but you can add a reference to a list of holidays to be discounted as well. The newer NETWORKDAYS.INTL has a large selection of built-in non-standard 'weekend' formats or you can write your own. e.g. `"0000011"` is a standard Sat/Sun weekend and `"0101000"` is a Tue and Thu 'weekend'.

Both NETWORKDAYS and NETWORKDAYS.INTL count the number of days inclusively so you are looking for a value of **2**, not 1.

For the following example, I've reset the computer's system date to Tue 19-Jan-2016 (the day after Martin Luther King Day, 2016).

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[calendar Date]], TODAY(), "0000011", Z$2:Z$11)=2, "Yes", "No")
```

If you wanted to get a little more elaborate, just use the NETWORKDAYS.INTL function with a custom number format of `[=2]\Y\e\s;\No;\No`. This allows you to retain the actual underlying value of the NETWORKDAYS.INTL formula while displaying Yes or No.

[image: NetWorkDays_Intl_Holidays]

The results from the image above clearly show that both the weekend and holiday were discarded from consideration and that Fri 15-Jan-2016 is considered the previous day.

---

¹ <sub>The [NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28) function was introduced with Excel 2013. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>